# How to store PubSub data to big query using cloud functions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, looker-studio

I am once again asking for your help.

Let me tell you my current situation first.

1. I have a device that connects to the "Cloud IoT core" and sends data using mqtt.
2. The data then goes to the Pub/Sub topic.
3. Then a "Cloud function" gets triggered which stores the data inside "Firestore"
4. Another "Cloud function" gets triggered which sends me an email with the stored data inside Firestore.

The size of the data is about 1 Kilobyte and I expect to send about 10K messages per Month

I need that data to create a dashboard for which I am using "Google Data Studio"

To get my data inside there I installed the Firebase extension "Stream Collections to BigQuery" to send the data to "BigQuery". from there I just had to click a few buttons to automaticly stream data from BigQuery to "Google Data Studio"

Everything works so far but as you can see I store the data 4 times. once via email, once inside firestore, once inside BigQuery and Data studio. All of this is going to cost alot of money in the long term, because the data stored doubles every Month.

What I need from You guys is some advice on best practices.

Is there a way to store the data directly inside BigQuery when it arrives in the Pub/Sub?
If so can I also send an email with the data as an attachment?

Is BigQuery a good solution or should I use "Cloud SQL"?

To save data inside Firestore I can execute the following inside a cloud function. Is there a similare way for BigQuery?

```
    firestore.collection("put Collection name here").doc(put document name here).set({
        'name' : name
        'age' : age

    }).then((writeResult) => {
        //console.log('Successfully executed set'); 
        return;
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    });
```

Comment: Update: I can now store pub/sub data in BigQuery  using a Cloud function. I Still need to research the email part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to store the data directly inside BigQuery when it
> arrives in the Pub/Sub?

Yes, you can use [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow) to build a streaming pipeline, as explained in different documentation items or blogs:

- [GCP Doc: Pub/Sub Topic to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#cloudpubsubtobigquery)
- [A Dataflow Journey: from PubSub to BigQuery](https://medium.com/codex/a-dataflow-journey-from-pubsub-to-bigquery-68eb3270c93)
- [Write a Pub/Sub Stream to BigQuery](https://faun.pub/writing-a-pub-sub-stream-to-bigquery-401b44c86bf)

But you could also use the [Node.js Client for BigQuery](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/index.html) in a Cloud Function, triggered by Pub/Sub. However, one could consider that this doesn't "store the data **directly**"...

> If so can I also send an email with the data as an attachment?

If you use a Cloud Function, that's quite easy, for example by using the dedicated ["Trigger Email" Firebase Extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-send-email).

You can also directly send an email from a Cloud Function by using the `nodemailer` package, see this [official Cloud Function sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/email-confirmation).

> Is BigQuery a good solution or should I use "Cloud SQL"?

It all depends on you exact use case... There is a lot of literature on the net: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=difference+between+Cloud+SQL+and+BigQuery

However, since you are going to use Data Studio, a classical answer would be to use BigQuery since it is best suited for analytics. But again, it depends on you exact use case.

(Note that this question alone would probably be closed on SO because it is [opinion based](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255468/opinion-based-questions)).

> To save data inside Firestore I can execute the following inside a
> cloud function. Is there a similar way for BigQuery?

Yes, as said above, use the [Node.js Client for BigQuery](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/index.html) in your Cloud Function.

Comment: Thank you @Renaud for your answer. I was just looking at Dataflow. Does that said Firebase extension work with BigQuery?  And  **However, one could consider that this doesn't "store the data directly"...** You mean that the data gets stored inside one column right? because that's what also happened with the extension stream to BigQuery and I had to use a script  provided by the firebase team to solve that problem.

Comment: "Does that said Firebase extension work with BigQuery" => Not sure to understand your question. Dataflow is not a Firebase extension, but another Google Cloud product. If you use Dataflow, you will not use the Firebase "Stream Collections to BigQuery" extension anymore.

Comment: "However, one could consider that this doesn't "store the data directly" => I just wanted to emphasize the fact that there is Cloud Function in the middle. Pub/Sub -> Cloud Function -> BigQuery. So it is not a **direct** Pub/Sub -> BigQuery. We can also say that Pub/Sub -> Dataflow -> BigQuery is not direct neither!! :-)

Comment: Sorry I asked my question wrong. You said **If you use a Cloud Function, that's quite easy, for example by using the dedicated Firebase Extension.** .  were you talking about **Trigger Email** extension?

Comment: "Were you talking about Trigger Email extension?" Yes!! You can also send the email from the Cloud Function directly, see this [sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/email-confirmation). The extension makes it easier and implements a robust error reporting, but creates an extra Firestore doc.

Comment: So to answer to ""Does the Trigger Email Firebase extension work with BigQuery" the answer is NO. It is another extension that you can use to easily send emails, but as said above it needs to create a Firestore doc.

Comment: **I just wanted to emphasize the fact that there is Cloud Function in the middle**. Now I understand :). What I meant with **store directly**  was to stop the use of 
Firestore.
 pub/sub -> cloud function -> firestore -> BigQuery.

to
pub/sub -> cloud function -> BigQuery.
once the data is stored in BigQuery then an email is send with the data as an attachment.